# git pull from local branch to local branch

Tags: git

I have 2 branches
BranchA
BranchB

To get code from BranchA to BranchB, I do this

```
- On BranchA - git commit -m "brancha changes"
- On BranchA - git push orign BranchA
- On BranchB - git pull origin BranchA
```

I want to skip step 2 and commit locally on A and pull in B locally. Sadly, cannot find how?

Comment: This is probably just a `git merge` or `git rebase`

Comment: git pull just calls git fetch and git merge. You can just merge directly. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout branch_a
git commit -m "branch_a changes"
git checkout branch_b
git rebase branch_a
```

Also last command can be replaced by `git merge branch_a`

If you just want to replace what you have in branch_b by branch_a, last command would be `git reset --hard branch_a`, that also works for remote branches, `git reset --hard origin/branch_a`, just make sure you run `git fetch origin` previously

Answer (score 1):

- On BranchA - git commit -m "brancha changes"
- On BranchB - git merge BranchA

This way you can merge two branches, the code of the BranchB will be up to date with the code of the BranchA.